# obtener un datos en Objetos en flutter

Tags: flutter, serialización

tengo el siguiente Widget , en la cual esta relacionado a un modelo o objetos, en la cual utilizo para seleccionar un dato y por el cual funciona bien

utilizo la siguiente librería
https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

el único problema es el onchangen que me devuelve el siguiente dato y solo necesito obtener el id_app

y desconozco la forma de obtener el siguiente dato

```
MantenimientoActividad{id: 2, id_app: 2 , nombre: FUNDIDA DE ALETAS EN DISIPADOR  LA YUCALA }
```

introducir el código aquí

```
Widget _buildTextField_actividad_id() {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: mantenimientoActividadDB.getDatas(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Container(
                    child: SearchableDropdown.single(
                      isExpanded: true,
                      //value: input_actividad_id.toString(),
                      //selectedItems: input_actividad_id,
                      //selectedItems: selectedItems,
                      //value: input_actividad_id.toString(),
    
                      hint: Text(input_actividad_id.toString() ??
                          'Seleciona una actividad'),
                      items: snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<MantenimientoActividad>>((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<MantenimientoActividad>(
                          value: item.toString(),
                          child: Text(item.nombre),
                        );
                      }).toList(),


    
                          onChanged: (value) {
//el value me imprimer MantenimientoActividad{id: 2, id_app: 2 , nombre: FUNDIDA DE ALETAS EN DISIPADOR  LA YUCALA }

                          
                        setState(() {
                          //input_actividad_id = int.parse(value.id_app);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Loading...'),
                    ),
                  );
          },
        );
      }
```

la salida de getData lo vota de la siguiente manera

```
[
MantenimientoActividad{id: 1, id_app: 1 , nombre:  DEMOLICION DE CONCRETO PARA CONSTRUCCIÓN FILTRO }, 
MantenimientoActividad{id: 2, id_app: 2 , nombre: FUNDIDA DE ALETAS EN DISIPADOR  LA YUCALA }, 
MantenimientoActividad{id: 3, id_app: 3 , nombre:  FUNDIDA DE SECCIONES DE DISIPADOR EN LA YUCALA }, 
MantenimientoActividad{id: 4, id_app: 4 , nombre: LIMPIEZA BERMA },....
```

Comment: has probado con `value: item.id.toString()`? o exactamente que te regresa `getDatas`(coloca un ejemplo si puedes)

Comment: ya lo intente y me vota el mensaje rojo <Mantenimiento> isn't dinamy

Comment: que te regresa `getDatas`?